# How to createElement of list/images in separate rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So below I have the HTML code that is part of my draggable/droppable:

```
   Drag from here:
        <ul id="sortable1" class="dropBox connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">Word 1</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Word 2</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Word 3</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Word 4</li>
        </ul>

    Drop a word onto each iamge: <br>
        <ul class = "row">
            <li id="drop1" class="dropZones images"><img src="image1.jpg"></li>
            <li id="drop2" class="dropZones images"><img src="image2.jpg"></li>          
        </ul>
        <ul class = "row">
            <li id="drop_zone3" class="dropZones images"><img src="image3.jpg"></li>
            <li id="drop_zone4" class="dropZones images"><img src="image4.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I am trying to create this using document.createElement() etc. But am having difficulty doing this efficiently.

The purpose of the rows (in above code) are for formatting (using bootstrap4), since there are 6 pictures total in my array, and I want 2 rows of 3.
Below, I have an array that holds all the images' src's. This array is passed into the function. I'm able to create one row/ul, with all of the li's/images inside. But I want to be able to create what I have above, with as little hard coding as possible and as efficiently as possible.

I have:

```
function createType3(arr)
{
  var count = 0;
  var length = arr.length;
  var list = document.createElement("ul");
  list.classList.add("row");

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    //create list and associated ids and classes
    var listPiece=document.createElement("li");
    listPiece.classList.add("dropZones","images","list-inline");
    listPiece.setAttribute("id","dropZone");
    //create image tags and append
    var imageSRC = document.createElement("IMG");
    imageSRC.setAttribute("src",arr[i]);

    listPiece.appendChild(imageSRC);
    list.appendChild(listPiece);
}

return list;
}
```

I'm having trouble doing this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a document fragment and add list elements to it. Create a new list whenever `i % 3` is zero. Make that 3 an argument so that you can use the function also for lists of any other number of entries:

```
function createType(arr, groupSize = 3) {
    var lists = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        list;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i % groupSize === 0) {
            list = document.createElement("ul");
            list.classList.add("row");
            lists.appendChild(list);
        }
        //create list and associated ids and classes
        var listPiece = document.createElement("li");
        listPiece.classList.add("dropZones","images","list-inline");
        listPiece.setAttribute("id","dropZone");
        //create image tags and append
        var imageSRC = document.createElement("IMG");
        imageSRC.setAttribute("src", arr[i]);

        listPiece.appendChild(imageSRC);
        list.appendChild(listPiece);
    }
    return lists;
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
var frag = createType(["img1.png","img2.png","img3.png","img4.png"], 3);
document.body.appendChild(frag); // add it somewhere in your HTML page
```